# IntelliJ IDEA output directory reverts to default target

Tags: intellij-idea

Running IntelliJ IDEA (10.5.4).  It is a Seam application.

In project structure --> artifacts --> Output directory, the default value is

```
...../proj/proj-web/target/classes.
```

I keep changing it to `......./proj/src/main/webapp` , which means the web server reads from the same directories I'm editing and my changes are viewable immediately.

My trouble is that IntelliJ frequently reverts back to the default and it is getting annoying.  Does anyone know how to make this stick.  This "didn't use to happen" in earlier versions.

Comment: Is that a Maven project?

Comment: IDEA will revert to the Maven configuration on every pom.xml re-import. You can disable it in the IDEA Maven settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try uncheck "use maven output directories"

[image]

Comment: I've been searching for this answer so long. Now I found it.

Answer (score 3):

Rename the artifact, this stops it getting overwritten on maven re-import.

Answer (score 1):

I think that isn't necessary to change output directory, because idea synchronizes src and output directory after make action. Or you can setup "update resources" in web server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and didn't want to change the "Use Maven output directories". My solution is to set the `webappDirectory` property of the `maven-war-plugin`configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <warName>myExampleWar</warName>
        <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        <webappDirectory>the/path/i/want/myExampleWar</webappDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For more details see:
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/exploded-mojo.html